# How to edit mnist dataset?

Tags: python, numpy, keras, dataset, mnist

I want to have digit 0 to 5 in the "mnist dataset".
How can I do this on python?
I try to solve this problem with numpy.delete, but it didn't work.

Comment: What does the dataset look like? You can probably use a slice with a condition on the index

Comment: @qmeeus mnist is collection of number have written with hand.

Comment: I know what it is, I'm asking how is the dataset implemented/stored

Comment: Can you write your code up to loading the mnist dataset of all digits?  Also show your try and how it did not work.  Then people can easily help you by adding a few lines to accomplish your objective.

Comment: @qmeeus numbers in this dataset don't have order.

Comment: See the comment of Kota Mori...

Comment: Train a network to identify all digits, then use that to filter out the ones less than 6 :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have the images stored in a numpy array of shape `(num_examples, num_pixels)` and the labels stored in an array of shape `(num_examples,)`, you can do this:

```
images = images[labels <= 5].copy()
labels = labels[labels <= 5].copy()
```

Comment: Thanks, but we can do this for labels. What can we do for images?

Comment: keep the indices and use it for images

Comment: The first line is for the images, the second line for the labels

Answer (score -2):

Try getting the images associated with labels in range(6). So, you can write a function similar to the the one below:

```
images_5 = []
label_5 = []
for img, label in zip(images, labels):
    if label in range(6):
        images_5.append(img)
        labels_5.append(label)
```

Not sure if it would work but i think it should!